# Sending and Receiving data in Sockets in Java

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to read and write the following data types : String, int and image in bytes through sockets.

I understand from the following answer that [Creating 2 streams with one socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170275/creating-2-streams-with-one-socket) I cannot have more than one stream in one socket.

1. Is it possible to use a common stream object for reading all the data types? If so, how do I differentiate between the data types.
2. If it is not possible to have a common stream object, should I create separate sockets for separate data types?

Thanks!

Comment: have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28464762/how-to-send-different-datatypes-over-in-a-socket-connection

Comment: You "could" serialise objects directly, this would give you starting point for a "common" wrapper object. Alternatively, you would need to devise a protocol which defined the "header" (which would include the type and possibly optional length), which is fixed size, which you can read off the socket first and then make determinations about how best to handle

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use a common stream object for reading all the data types?

Yes, for example `DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream`.

> If so, how do I differentiate between the data types.

Via your application protocol. You either always send the same datatypes in the same order, or you send message types with each message so the peer knows what is coming.

> If it is not possible to have a common stream object, should I create separate sockets for separate data types?

Not necessary.